# Application is faster when profiling

Tags: c++, qt, profiling

I have an OpenGL Qt application which is behaving strangely when being analyzed by Very sleepy. When I execute it without Very Sleepy activated, I have 15 fps for my scene rendering. When I activate profiling of that application on Very Sleepy, my fps increases a lot (I get 96 fps during the whole analysis phase), and when I stop the analysis, the fps switches back to 15 fps. I also notice that the GUI responds faster during the analysis.

I have also noticed that during the analysis, my application uses less CPU (20% instead of 50%)

This is very puzzling. As you can guess, I'd like to have that kind of performance without very sleepy! What could happen during the analysis phase that could "speed up" the program? The application was built in release mode, and is ran as a standalone in both cases. I've been searching for hours on the Internet, to no avail.

Comment: Are you using multiple threads?

Comment: yes, I have multiple threads (around 10), most of them are sleeping 95% of the time.

Comment: Are you running this application from an IDE?

Comment: Then I'd look if you got a synchronization/communication problem between the threads (them fighting over a mutex as a simple example). The profiling overhead might slow the threads down a bit so they don't fight over resources so much and in fact overall speed it up. I've only ever had such weird behavior with heavy multithreading but it's usually hard to find.

Comment: What's the system/platform? This sounds very much like it could be a power management issue. To really analyze performance in a reliable way, you typically need either a way to lock the system at a certain power state (or clock frequency), or you need to at least capture the current clock frequencies as part of your measurements.

Comment: As it turned out, I was spamming locks/unlocks on a thread. Thanks for your help guys!